# Cannot convert from ulong[] to double[]

Tags: c#

MSDN says, that conversion from `ulong` to `double` can be done implicitly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx. But when I try to compile the following:

```
public static double arraySum(double[] arrN)
{
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (double k in arrN)
    sum += k;
    return sum;
}

ulong[] chessArray = new ulong[64]
//filling values of chessArray, 1st element is 1, 2nd is 2, 3rd is 4 etc.    
ulong a = arraySum(chessArray);
```

I get a compiler error CS1503 "Cannot convert from ulong[] to double[]". What's the reason? My guess is that in this particular case the values of last array elements are extremely high, i.e. chessArray[63] is even higher (by 1) then maximum of `ulong`: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: MSDN  says that you can implicitly convert `ulong` to `double`. Not `ulong[]` to `double[]`.

Comment: Just because there's an implicit conversion from some type `T` to `U` doesn't mean there's an implicit conversion from arrays of `T` to arrays of `U` i.e. implicit conversions are not automatically lifted over array types.

Comment: But you are doing a double to long.  This works : ulong a = (ulong)chessArray.Select(x => (double)x).Sum();

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert an array of `ulong` to an array of `double`, which is impossible.

Try to convert each value inside your method, instead:

```
public static double arraySum(ulong[] arrN)
{
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (ulong k in arrN){
        sum+=(double)k;
    }
    return sum;
}

ulong[] chessArray = new ulong[64]
//filling values of chessArray, 1st element is 1, 2nd is 2, 3rd is 4 etc.    
ulong a = arraySum(chessArray);
```

Comment: In my opinion best answer in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from ulong to double, but you cannot convert from double to ulong. When you try to convert the array, also the latter conversion must be possible because an array is writable.

Just look at an example which shows the problematic consequence:

```
ulong[] chessArray = new ulong[64];
double[] doubleArray = chessArray; // let's assume it is allowed
doubleArray[0] = 1.23; // what should happen here with chessArray[0]?
```

Comment: Pls rewrite more exlipcity, idea is 100% OK, but average SO reader can understand wrong.